# Number of $n \times n$ binary matrices whose rows and columns sum to at most $m$

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, matrices

How many matrices satisfy the following constraints?

1. $n$ rows
2. $n$ columns
3. Cell values are either $0$ or $1$
4. Sum of any row is at most $m$
5. sum of any column is at most $m$

Is there a formula or an efficient algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: I can solve the cases $m=0$ and $m=1$.

Comment: This is the same as the number of digraphs where the in-degree and out-degree are bounded by $m$.

Comment: This has some connection to Latin Squares. In particular, we can take an $n\times n$ Latin Square, set the numbers from 1 to $m$ to be 1, and the numbers from $m+1$ to $n$ to be 0. Good news is that this gives a lower bound on your problem. Two problems: 1. the number of Latin squares of size $n$ is an open problem (known bounds are thought to be fairly weak), and 2. it's not clear to me how tight this bound is. In particular, while every Latin square is a solution to your problem, I'm not sure when a solution to this problem can be turned into a Latin Square.

Answer (score 4):

Given $1 \leq m \leq n$, we want to determine the **cardinality** of the following set

$$\{ \mathrm X \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n} \mid \mathrm X 1_n \leq m 1_n \,\land\,  \mathrm 1_n^{\top} \mathrm X \leq m \mathrm 1_n^{\top} \}$$

Vectorizing, $\tilde{\mathrm x} := \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X)$, we obtain

$$\bigg\{ \tilde{\mathrm x} \in \{0,1\}^{n^2} : \begin{bmatrix} 1_n^{\top} \otimes \mathrm I_n\\ \mathrm I_n \otimes \mathrm 1_n^{\top}\end{bmatrix} \tilde{\mathrm x} \leq m \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm 1_n\\ \mathrm 1_n\end{bmatrix} \bigg\}$$

or,

$$\bigg\{ \tilde{\mathrm x} \in [0,1]^{n^2} : \begin{bmatrix} 1_n^{\top} \otimes \mathrm I_n\\ \mathrm I_n \otimes \mathrm 1_n^{\top}\end{bmatrix} \tilde{\mathrm x} \leq m \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm 1_n\\ \mathrm 1_n\end{bmatrix} \bigg\} \cap \mathbb Z^{n^2}$$

Thus, we want to count the number of [integer points inside a convex polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_points_in_convex_polyhedra), or, in other words, to count the number of solutions a given integer program (IP) has. Take a look at De Loera's survey [0] and the references therein.

---

[0] Jesús De Loera, [The Many Aspects of Counting Lattice Points in Polytopes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/RECENT_WORK/semesterberichte.pdf), 2005.